# Using lintr with sublime text 3

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I am trying to use [SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr](https://github.com/jimhester/SublimeLinter-contrib-lintr) in sublime text 3. I have problems understanding the install instructions.

> In order for R to be executed by SublimeLinter, you must ensure that its path is available to SublimeLinter. Before going any further, please read and follow the steps in “Finding a linter executable” through “Validating your PATH” in the documentation.

I have installed [lintr](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) by using the `devtools` package in R. I have looked in the folder where `lintr`was installed, but I cannot find any executables.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 2):

I believe the executable that needs to be found is **R** itself, not lintr, because the lintr package will be called by R. Accordingly, once you have edited your PATH, you should issue these commands [to validate it](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#validating-your-path):

```
# Mac OS X, Linux
$SHELL -l -c '/usr/bin/which R'

# Windows
where R
```

Comment: I have a short follow up question if you don't mind. I've added the `R` path to the `SublimeLinter3` settings, however `lintr` is still not running. Am I missing any obvious steps? I followed carefuly the instructions on the http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#finding-a-linter-executable. Only difference is that I didn't install using `devtools`, but rather used the `pkg` available on `CRAN`. Do you have any ideas how to get it to work?

Comment: I am having the same problem on macOS 10.13.4 with Sublime Text 3 build 3170.  R is installed and on my path; the lintr package is installed in R; SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-contro-lintr are installed.  The strange thing is when I first restarted Sublime there was linting (e.g. highlighting missing spaces around =) but on subsequent restarts there is no linting.  Any suggestions for getting lintr working in Sublime?

Comment: This is a different question from the original question. Please write it as a new Slashdot question, referencing this question if need be.